# Running time of sorting with a black-box findmax subroutine

Tags: algorithm, sorting

Suppose you had a black-box subroutine that could extract the max from an array of n elements in `(log n)^a` time, where `0 <= a <= 1`. You're trying to create an optimal sorting algorithm that makes use of this subroutine.

The obvious solution is to call the subroutine on the entire array, swap the max with the last element, and then call the sub-routine iteratively on `A[1, n-1]` through `A[1, 2]`.

Is there a better algorithm that runs faster than `n*(log n)^a` time, or is the obvious solution optimal?

Comment: First observation: you can't do better if you don't use the black box max routine

Comment: He didn't say that you had a better way to compare items.

Comment: Seems like if you used it as just a way to do comparisons between two elements, you could then use something like Quicksort to minimize the number of comparisons you'd have to do. Which might make it faster since log n is obviously smaller as n is smaller.

Comment: @Yuriy: the more I think along these lines, the more I find n log^a n. Even if you cut the array in say sqrt(n) equal pieces and you cleverly try to merge results, you can't fight math: O(log^a(sqrt(n))) = O(log^a(n)).

Comment: It's interesting that `a` is left as a parameter, so eventually the optimal algorithms could depend on the value of `a`. For example, for `a = 0` your proposal sorts in `O(n)` time (which is hard to beat if one has to place each of the `n` values anyway into the sorted array) while for `a = 1` there seems to be no asymptotic gain over well-known sorting algorithms even though the maximum of a completely unsorted array can be found in `O(log(n))` time with the black box (compared to `O(n)` like one would expect)...

Answer (score 4):

No. In expectation, we need Ω(n log n) bits from the black box to sort n items. When called on an array of size k, the black box runs for (log k)<sup>a</sup> steps and returns about log k bits, for a rate of about (log k)<sup>1 - a</sup> bits per step. This rate is upperbounded by (log n)<sup>1 - a</sup>, so the obvious algorithm is asymptotically optimal.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the exact answer, but here's some results that hint the answer might be the naive one:

Suppose we divide the input into 4 pieces (4 can be substituted by k);

Sorting on each of the 4 pieces takes n/4*(log(n/4)^a), combining the results need (n/2+n/2+n) = 2n;

n/4*(log(n/4)^a) * 4 = n(logn^a)-n/4*(log4)^a,

total time = n(logn^a) - n/4*(log4)^a + 2n

However, if a = 1, rhs = n(log(n)^a); if a < 1, rhs > n(log(n)^a).

So even considering from a real world perspective rather than the Big-Oh perspective, the divide & conquer approach can only slow it down if a<1 and there are no benefits when a=1.

I don't know if there are other tricks, however. Hope this could at least provoke some ideas!

Comment: If you try to make k a function of n, it doesn't seem to work either. At least k = polynomial(n) doesn't work. Maybe other functions of n ?

Comment: @Alexsandre Yes, but type the general case is a task too tiring:) And it just occurs to me that since a could be 1, if the required solution was found, then if it works with 1 we would beat CAR Hoare, which is unlikely.

Comment: The case a = 1 will indeed not admit improvements, but a < 1 could.